# GRUB does not show on startup

Tags: grub2, partitioning, 15.04, wubi, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 10, but at startup the grub menu does not show. I used Wubi before, and I uninstalled it from the control panel, selecting the Ubuntu application. Is this relevant?

Also, when creating the disk partition, it asked me where to install the grub and I chose the newly created partition. Was it the right choice?

Comment: Wubi is obsolete. Is your Windows 10 install UEFI or CSM/BIOS? What brand/model system? Did you then install Ubuntu in the same boot mode as Windows. Generally you install grub2's boot loader to a drive like sda. Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: No you shouldn't have installed grub to the partition, it has to go on the drive i.e. /dev/sda instead of /dev/sdaX

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to boot up the computer you can edit the grub configuration to display options.  Since you are indicating that grub isn't showing up, you'll need to comment out the line that says `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=`.

Also add a timeout number for the display time such as:

```
 GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

As far as the boot option you mentioned, since it's working with the boot partition at this time, I'd leave it there.  But in the future it might be easier to select a boot drive for the grub installation such as `/dev/sdX` (ie. /dev/sda).

By the way I see you included "wubi" as a tag option.  This doesn't have anything to do with wubi.

Comment: I added Wubi because i wondered if it was a problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok this time i chose to install the bootloader into /dev/sda, but during the installation process i got this:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/999) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 999! (This could e g happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
```

The progress bar is stopped, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert with this kind of stuffs, but a few days before, I saw this [tutorial on super grub](https://youtu.be/Lkz2Q_F77lM). The tutorial says to install `super grub 2` on a USB device. Then you can use it to log into your ubuntu (or windows). Once you are in, you can try various repairing commands. such as, `$ sudo update-grub` always does the job for me. Good luck.